# Has the NaNoWriMo ever been completed in Esperanto?

Tags: literature

[NaNoWriMo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Novel_Writing_Month) is an event where people try to write a novel with more than 50 000 words during the month of November. The 2013 edition had 310 095 participants and 42 221 winners.

I know some people have tried to make a novel in Esperanto for NaNoWriMo, but I never saw someone claiming completing it with proof.

Comment: Oooh a nice complement to the sumoo. Hehe. Let's flood the internet with Esperanto fan fiction. 

Comment: I believe the NaNoWriMo can be completed any way you want, even a book filled with `kio la fek` 17,000 times would be valid.

Answer (score 3):

On [Rober L. Read's blog](https://esperanto-usa.org/en/node/888) I found that two people participated in Esperanto.
Unfortunately, the links that he link to are dead. I imagine that they would be the evidence we're looking for.

I found this, too: [Goulo's livejournal.](http://goulo.livejournal.com/291437.html)

Other than that, this person on tumblr seems to have participated: [Pretervola alhxemisto](http://pretervolaalhhemiisto.tumblr.com/).

And we'll see what comes out of this:  [gerogeropyo](https://gerogeropyo.wordpress.com/tag/nanowrimo/) - this person is planning to participate this year! Good luck! Update 2019: Unfortunately, this Wordpress page has been deleted.

And this person that also blogs about Esperanto participated successfully in English in 2013: [Arion's home](http://www.arionshome.com/category/culture/writing/national-novel-writing-month-nanowrimo/). Maybe we'll see something in Esperanto one day? :-)

Comment: I followed the link of Goulo. I can not find his work. His novel(s) might be in English, and he later translated the message that he made about it.